# What are all the jars in External Library section in intellij maven project

Tags: intellij-idea

So on the left hand side of Intellij,I have my project as a collapsable element and beneath it is External Libraries section. I'm not sure what are all those jars in the section.

For instance, some of those jars - first few of them are highlighted with (library home) in brackets written with it.
Then I see a different kind of directory (different icon) called < 1. 7 > With its path in brackets as well. Inside it, it also has many jars saying library home.
Then I've different kind of icon for directories with structure like Maven: group-id:artifact-id:version.

I'm confused as to why are some of these from maven and others from my library home, and how they got there in the first place.

Googling up anything about libraries in intellij floods result related to how to add a 3rd party library to intellij project, which I am not very interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ones called `< 1.7 >` are the core libraries from the java SDK (version 7 in your case).

The ones with (library home) are set up via the `Project Structure` - ctrl + alt + shift + s.

In the project structure you can define jars or directories in `Project Settings` -> `Libraries` or `Platform Settings` -> `Global Libraries`. These configure the libraries to be project-specific or global to all your projects.

From there, you need to go in to `Project Settings` -> `Modules` and configure exactly which libraries are configured for your module (use the green `+` sign on the right side to add them).

When a library is assigned to a module in this way, you will see it appear under the `External Libraries`. Likewise, you can use the minus `-` to remove them.

Lastly, maven style depenencies are picked up automatically from the `<dependencies>` section of your `pom.xml` (ensure maven auto-import is always on, so they stay up to date).